# How to generate .sln for php-src on Windows

Tags: php, c, windows, visual-studio

I want to read php source code(ZendPHP source code) in Visual Studio. How to do it?

Comment: Voted to close as it is unclear what you're actually asking, and because this is not the place to ask questions on specific tools, especially if the question isn't directly code related. Lastly: take a look at the hackers' guide to the zend engine on the php website

Comment: Not sure this is what you're after, but: if you just want the source tree displayed in VS so you can browse it to open files etc: create a new Makefile project or so and save it in the root of the source tree. Making sure 'Show All Files' option is on you can then browse the source.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By default Visual Studio doesn't ship with support for PHP. You can add support using an extension or edit the php files as part of a WebApplication project (in which case you will receive very basic editing support).

There are a [bunch of extensions for Visual Studio which support PHP as a supported language in Visual Studio.](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=SearchText&f%5B0%5D.Value=php&f%5B1%5D.Type=Tag&f%5B1%5D.Value=php&f%5B2%5D.Type=VisualStudioVersion&f%5B2%5D.Value=14.0&f%5B2%5D.Text=Visual%20Studio%202015) I personally used the [ones from DevSense a long, long time ago](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=SearchText&f%5B0%5D.Value=php&f%5B1%5D.Type=VisualStudioVersion&f%5B1%5D.Value=14.0&f%5B1%5D.Text=Visual%20Studio%202015&f%5B2%5D.Type=RootCategory&f%5B2%5D.Value=tools&f%5B2%5D.Text=Tools&f%5B3%5D.Type=User&f%5B3%5D.Value=DEVSENSE&f%5B3%5D.Text=DEVSENSE).

If you don't want to use an extension (for whatever reason) you can create an empty Web Application project and manually add your php files to it and set them to "content". That way the php files will be copied when you publish the application. You can remove any items that are .NET specific such as a default web page and the app.config.